# How can I skip test cases when some value is falsy in beforeEach hook?

Tags: jestjs

I use `jest.js` to write my test suites. Here is the sample:

```js
describe('test suites', () => {
  let user;
  beforeEach(async () => {
    user = await userSerivce.getUserById('1');

    if (!user) {
      console.info('user not found. Skip all test cases');
      // break;
    }
  });

  if (user) {
    it('t-1', () => {
      /**/
    });
    it('t-2', () => {
      /**/
    });
  }
});
```

I want to skip all test cases and log a message to stdout when the user is not found.

But got:

```
 FAIL  src/condition-skip-all-test-cases/index.spec.ts
  ● Test suite failed to run

    Your test suite must contain at least one test.

      at node_modules/jest/node_modules/jest-cli/build/TestScheduler.js:256:22

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
Tests:       0 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        1.455s
Ran all test suites matching /src\/condition-skip-all-test-cases/i.
npm ERR! Test failed.  See above for more details.
```

How can I achieve this? thanks.

I found an issue similar to my question. https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/3652

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my solution:

`index.spec.ts`:

```js
const userService = {
  async getUserById(id: string): Promise<object | null> {
    return null;
  }
};

export const itif = (name: string, condition: () => boolean | Promise<boolean>, cb) => {
  it(name, async done => {
    if (await condition()) {
      cb(done);
    } else {
      console.warn(`[skipped]: ${name}`);
      done();
    }
  });
};

describe('condition-skip-all-test-cases test suites', () => {
  async function isUserExists() {
    const user = await userService.getUserById('1');
    return user ? true : false;
  }

  let getUserByIdSpy;
  async function conditionWithMock() {
    getUserByIdSpy = jest.spyOn(userService, 'getUserById').mockResolvedValueOnce({ userId: 1 });
    return isUserExists();
  }

  itif('should skip the test if no user found by id', isUserExists, done => {
    expect('run test').toBe('run test');
    done();
  });

  itif('should run the test if user found by id', conditionWithMock, done => {
    console.log('should run this test');
    expect.assertions(3);
    expect('run test').toBe('run test');
    expect(jest.isMockFunction(userService.getUserById)).toBeTruthy();
    getUserByIdSpy.mockRestore();
    expect(jest.isMockFunction(userService.getUserById)).toBeFalsy();
    done();
  });
});
```

Unit test result:

```sh
 PASS  src/condition-skip-all-test-cases/index.spec.ts (15.336s)
  condition-skip-all-test-cases test suites
    ✓ should skip the test if no user found by id (38ms)
    ✓ should run the test if user found by id (11ms)

  console.warn src/condition-skip-all-test-cases/index.spec.ts:14
    [skipped]: should skip the test if no user found by id

  console.log src/condition-skip-all-test-cases/index.spec.ts:38
    should run this test

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       2 passed, 2 total
Snapshots:   0 total
```